# How do I trim the zero value after decimal

Tags: vb6

As I tried to debug, I found that : just as I type in

```
Dim value As Double
value = 0.90000
```

then hit enter, and it automatically converts to 0.9

Shouldn't it *keep the precision in double in visual basic*?

For my calculation, I absolutely need to show the precision

Comment: You could try storing it as a string instead? Then cast when necessary...

Comment: @Longball - For the love of programming please don't suggest that.

Comment: btw this is visual basic application not .NET

Answer (score 2):

If precision is required then the `Currency` data type is what you want to use.

Comment: See my answer - it looks like that's fixed at 4 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two representations of your value in play. One is the value you see on the screen -- a string -- and one is the internal representation -- a binary value. In dealing with fractional values, the two are often not equivalent and where they aren't, it's because they can't be.

If you stick with doubles, VB will maintain 53 bits of mantissa throughout your calculations, no matter how they might appear when printed. If you transition through the string domain, say by saving to a file or DB and later retrieving, it often has to leave some of that precision behind. It's inevitable, because the interface between the two domains is not perfect. Some values that can be exactly represented as strings (or Decimals, that is, powers of ten) can't be exactly represented as fractional powers of 2.

This has nothing to do with VB, it's the nature of floating point. The best you can do is control where the rounding occurs. For this purpose your friend is the Format function, which controls how a value appears in string form.

? Format$(0.9, "0.00000") will show you an example.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting what you see on the screen confused with what bits are being set in the Double to make that number.

VB is simply being "helpful", and simply knocking off excess zeros.  But for all intents and purposes,

```
0.9
```

is identical to

```
0.90000
```

If you don't believe me, try doing this comparison:

```
Debug.Print CDbl("0.9") = CDbl("0.90000")
```

As has already been said, displayed precision can be shown using the Format$() function, e.g.

```
Debug.Print Format$(0.9, "0.00000")
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't keep the precision. Binary floating point values don't retain this information... and it would be somewhat odd to do so, given that you're expressing the value in one base even though it's being represented in another.

I don't know whether VB6 has a *decimal* floating point type, but that's probably what you want - or a fixed point decimal type, perhaps. Certainly in .NET, `System.Decimal` has retained extra 0s from .NET 1.1 onwards. If this doesn't help you, you could think about remembering two integers - e.g. "90000" and "100000" in this case, so that the value you're representing is one integer divided by another, with the associated level of precision.

EDIT: I thought that `Currency` may be what you want, but [according to this article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5885671.html), that's fixed at 4 decimal places, and you're trying to retain 5. You could potentially just multiply by 10, if you *always* want 5 decimal places - but it's an awkward thing to remember to do everywhere... and you'd have to work out how to format it appropriately. It would also *always* be 4 decimal places, I suspect, even if you'd specified fewer - so if you want "0.300" to be different to "0.3000" then `Currency` may not be appropriate. I'm entirely basing this on articles online though...

Comment: Somehow I get the feeling that they won't be rolling their own `Decimal` object. What I am trying to say is that `Currency` is probably their only option.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: We don't really know enough about the requirements to say (in particular how strong the requirements are compared with the amount of time available to implement them) - other than that it looks like `Currency` isn't a 100% fit. It may be the closest that exists built into VB, of course.

Comment: Agreed. I bet we can also agree that `Currency` should have been designed more generically. High precision is not only for financial calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enter the value as **0.9#** instead.  This helps avoid implicit coercion within an expression that may truncate the precision you expect.  In most cases the compiler won't require this hint though because floating point literals default to Double (indeed, the IDE typically deletes the # symbol unless the value was an integer, e.g. **9#**).

Contrast the results of these:

```
MsgBox TypeName(0.9)
MsgBox TypeName(0.9!)
MsgBox TypeName(0.9@)
```